# USB Hub reset/update

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

I made some changes and I don’t know exactly what.

In Device Manager I changed a USB port with the name Intel and something after that. I changed some settings for this USB port and I had to restart my computer. After I restarted it, I couldn’t use my mouse and keyboard. I tried every other USB port on my computer but it still doesn’t work. I also can’t get into the safe mode in Windows 10. 
I pressed every F key with and without Strg but it still doesn’t work.. I have no idea how to fix this issue

Comment: What settings for a USB port do you believe you changed, as Windows' Device Manager usually only allows changing the power management options for the device? For Safe Mode, it's entered into two ways via the GUI: Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced Startup - Troubleshoot > Advanced > Startup Options or by turning off the PC 2x in a row when the BIOS/UEFI hands off to the Windows bootloader _(i.e. as soon as the "Windows" loading screen appears)_

Comment: I followed this instructions  : go into your divice manager and change the driver for ASMedia USB 3.1 Host Controller (but I didn’t find it so I selected something with intel in the name). Right click it, choose “ update driver”, then choose “browse my computer for driver software”. Choose “let me pick from a list...”. Untick “Show compatible hardware “, choose “(standard USB Host Controller) from the menu on the left and select “USB xHCI complaint Host Controller”( also didn’t find it so I selected something similar to that )from the box on the right.

Comment: Why would you decide to change the default Windows 10 driver for the ASMedia device?

Comment: I had some issues with the software from the oculus rift s so I searched in the internet for solutions and yeah...

Answer (score 0):

> I made some changes and I don’t know exactly what.

You killed the normal USB xHCI driver with something "similar to that", which obviously was not similar. Now you need to install Windows 10 default driver somehow, either to restore your Windows from a restore point, although quite unlikely (since you likley has no restore points :-( ).
You can try to plug in a separate PCIe USB controller card (any xHCI card will do), and plug your mouse/keyboard into it. Windows will load correct driver for this card, and you will be able regain control over your PC. Then don't do any initiatives and load standard drivers by uninstalling your crippled on-board xHCI, and re-enabling them by re-scanning device tree. Good luck.

Comment: So can I plug in a old keyboard with a ps/2 port into my mainboard to reset the USB ports?